# ReCaptcha issue in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, recaptcha

i'm using this [pod](https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha) to use Google reCaptcha when users authenticate to an iOS app.

The captcha is shown, but not clickable.
in my `loginViewController`:

```
private var recaptcha: ReCaptcha?
private var locale: Locale = Locale(identifier: "fr-FR")
private var endpoint = ReCaptcha.Endpoint.default
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     do {
          recaptcha = try ReCaptcha(apiKey: Config.API_KEY, baseURL: URL(string: "http://localhost"), endpoint: .default, locale: locale)
        }
     catch {
          print("error")
        }
     recaptcha?.configureWebView { [weak self] webview in
                webview.frame = self?.view.bounds ?? CGRect.zero
            }
     recaptcha?.forceVisibleChallenge = true
  }

func validate(){
    recaptcha?.validate(on: view, resetOnError: true, completion: { (ReCaptchaResult) in
        switch ReCaptchaResult {
        case .error:
            print("error")
        case .token:
            //WHAT TO DO WITH THE TOKEN HERE?
            guard let userName = self.userNameTextField.text, let password = self.passwordTextField.text else {
                return
            }
            self.authentificationPresenter.authenticate(userName: userName, password: password)
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped() {        
    validate()
}
```

The result is this. I don't understand how to go from here, and interpret the user's result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the Captcha is loaded in a webview and to my knowledge would not be directly displayed on a ViewController is it possible that your Captcha is is somehow covered by an empty view? This may be why it is not "clickable". Either that or perhaps you need to enable interactions inside of your webview - you can try adding this when you configure the web view:

`webview.isUserIntractionEnabled = true`

As far as interpreting the result, if the user successfully completes the Captcha test you should receive a client token which you will use alongside your API secret key in a post request to the endpoint provided. Here is the documentation for verifying the user following the completion of a Captcha test: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify. Hope this helped.

Comment: webview.isUserIntractionEnabled = true does not work. the webview still not clickable